# Contextual view -> entity reference target ID

Tags: views, entities, chaos-tool-suite

I have the following situation:

I have 2 content types (session and preformance)

Performance has an entity reference to session

I want to create a view that shows me all performances for the session that is referenced by the performance i am looking at right now.

So this is a contextual view that filters on the nid of the performance, and has a relation to the session that is referenced by the viewed performance.

I cannot get the target_id of the session (from field_session on content type performance) to be passed in as a contextual filter.

I tried to use %node:field_session, but that gives me the label of the session, and not the target_id.

I also tried to change the display of the performance content type->field_session to 'entity id', but no luck.

All suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the proper Context to the variant.

[image]

Then you complete the setup.

[image]

And lastly you select it in the panel settings for the Contextual view:

[image]

Comment: Dear J.Reynolds, Thanks so much for this very clear explanation!

I did not fully understand where in my view i can find the last stem to select the sessions contextual filter.
I can't seem to find it in my contextual filters config on the view.

Ps: Its a views content pane.

Comment: Dear J.Reynolds,

I figured it out, i think :-)
I now have it working as follows:

On my page variant i added the context as described and added the %session_node:nid in my argument input on pane config.

What i dont understand is that on the context screen of my page variant, when i look at %session_node, i also see fields that are not attached to that content type? (not a problem at this point, but i want to fully understand).

Thanks again!!!